# Javascript loop very inefficient......Why?

Tags: javascript, performance, loop

I am not a javascript expert but thought this was a slam dunk to code until I saw the results. I am looking for help to make this MUCH more efficient.

I have a simple for-loop going over a list of data rows. Typically there are 10 or so but sometimes there might be up to a couple of thousand. With 10 its no problem. With 1200 it takes 34 seconds!!

The code -

```
           for(let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                selectedRows[i].checked = event.target.checked;
            }
```

I am setting the "checked" variable in all rows to true or false. i.e. someone selected the "Check all boxes" checkbox.

As mentioned above, with 1200 rows it takes 34 seconds. When I add timers in like the following -

```
            for(let i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                console.time('handle checking of box - ' + i);
                selectedRows[i].checked = event.target.checked;
                console.timeEnd('handle checking of box - ' + i);
            }
```

what is interesting is that the loop starts out fast. It does a row in about 1ms which is what I would expect.

[image]

But, as the loop progresses it gets much slower until at the end each row takes 20ms.

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why the loop gets slower and slower as well as perhaps a better way of doing this?

Comment: Might improve performance by caching `const checked = event.target.checked` and/or switching to `selectedRows.forEach` so you don't have to index in every time.

Comment: I'm not a JS expert either, but the first thing that came to mind is that your browser may be doing 're-flows'/'re-paints' every time you change a checkbox. Perhaps LWC/Aura has a way to mitigate that, but failing that I believe the general approach is to make your modifications to a "document fragment" (i.e. a partial html document), then substitute the existing fragment (with no boxes checked) with the modified fragment (with all boxes checked).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two changes should help you improve performance:

1. Cache the results of `event.target.checked` in advance.
2. Use a `forEach` loop so you don't have to index in every time.

As you already discovered, the end result should look like:

```
const checked = event.target.checked;
selectedRows.forEach(row => row.checked = checked);
```

Comment: The reason why is Locker Service: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/333158

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @AdrianLarson. (I would have marked his answer correct if it wasn't a comment!) I looked into forEach and it solved the problem. Not exactly sure technically why forEach is better than using a regular for-loop but its now lightning fast. Here is the code for anyone interested -

```
        const checked = event.target.checked
        selectedRows.forEach(element => element.checked = checked);
```

The loop now takes **10ms** total which is orders of magnitude quicker.

Comment: I'll post as an answer. It was just pretty speculative.

Comment: The reason why is Locker Service: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/333158