# updating js object in lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have to change an attribute of a JSON object.
Ex.

```
allOppList= [[{"A":"2051-11-21","B":"FLOAT"}]]
```

I have to change the B to "xyz" in the JS file.

I am doing by below code but I am not able to update the B element

```
let tempAllRecords = Object.assign([], this.allOppList);
        for (let j = 0; j < this.allOppList.length; j++) {
                let tempRec = Object.assign({}, tempAllRecords[j]);
                tempRec.B = event.detail.checked;
                tempAllRecords[j] = tempRec;
        }
        this.allOppList = tempAllRecords;
```

in this way, "B" of `allOppList` is not getting updated. Instead, it is getting updated like below

```
allOppList= [[{"A":"2051-11-21","B":"FLOAT"},"B":"New value"]]
```

Comment: You have nested arrays, you will need two nested for loops, and you can do this in the inner for loop.

Answer (score 1):

As a performance matter, do not use for-index loops in LWC within Salesforce, or you'll suffer [extreme performance penalties](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/333158/2984). You do have a nested loop, so the best way to do this is a nested map operation:

```
let tempAllRecords = this.allOppList.map(
  innerList => innerList.map(
    innerItem => ({ ...innerItem, B: event.detail.checked })
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks! but getting  [e.map is not a function] error

Comment: @Babu make sure you have an actual list first. You'd get this error if this.allOppList were a String or something else. You may need JSON.parse before you operate on the value if it is an actual JSON string.

Comment: even after parsing the json I am getting  [s.map is not a function] error. let tempData4=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.allOppList[0]));
            console.log('tempData4>>>>>>>>>>>>'+tempData4);
            let tempData3 = tempData4.map(
                innerList => innerList.map(
                    innerItem => ({ ...innerItem, noSeats : chnagedNoSeats })
                  )
            );