# Iterating api variable on nested lwc is very slow

Tags: lightning-web-components, performance

I am experiencing a weird behaviour when iterating a relatively big list in an lwc api variable when this is going through nested components. When I have two nested components the time taken to iterate the list is significantly slower than the same operation when there is only one nested component.

In both cases a parent component is fetching a list of dtos using imperative Apex. I have a button on the last component just to initiate a `.map` call to the list of dtos.

**First example**

Time taken: **17 seconds**

The parent provides the list to the child component through an api variable which in turn passes it through an other api variable to the grandchild component.

**Second example**

Time taken: **133 milliseconds**

The parent provides the data to the grandchild component through an api.

---

Below is the code for the components:

For the second example I just modify the `parent.html` by changing `<c-child foos={foos}></c-child>` to `<c-grandchild foos={foos}></c-grandchild>`

```
public with sharing class Controller {  
  public class Foo {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String bar {get; set;}
  }

  @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Foo> getFoos(){
    List<Foo> foos = = new List<Foo>();

    for(Integer i=0; i<4000; i++) {
      Foo foo = new Foo();
      foo.bar = 'foo' + i;
      foos.add(foo);
    }

    return foos;
  }
}
```

```
// Parent.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getFoos from '@salesforce/apex/Controller.getFoos';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {
    foos;

    get foosAvailable() {
        return this.foos !== undefined;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        getFoos()
            .then((data) => {
                this.foos = data;
            });
    }
}
```

```
<!-- parent.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <template if:false={foosAvailable}>
            <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">Foos loading...</div>
        </template>

        <template if:true={foosAvailable}>
            <c-child foos={foos}></c-child>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
// child.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
    @api foos;
}
```

```
<!-- child.html -->
<template>
    <c-grandchild foos={foos}></c-grandchild>
</template>
```

```
// grandchild.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Grandchild extends LightningElement {
    @api foos;

    handleClick() {
        const startTime = performance.now();
        this.foos.map(foo => foo);
        const endTime = performance.now();

        console.log(`Map call took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`);
    }
}
```

```
<!-- grandchild.html -->
<template>
    <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-button
            variant="brand"
            label="Start"
            onclick={handleClick}>
        </lightning-button>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't LWC, but rather Locker Service. I've [explained this before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/333161/2984), but I also wrote a [new demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/XQHAYTmxazblnaULrYQp/src/parent.html) that shows that sub-second performance is expected. When using Locker Service, data is proxied, which can have significant performance impacts. However, this can be mitigated by copying the array:

## Before

[image: Before copy implementation]

## After

[image: After copy implementation]

The difference is that we copy the values before iterating over them:

## grandchild.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Grandchild extends LightningElement {
    _foos;
    @api set foos(value) {
        this._foos = [...value];
    }
    get foos() {
        return this._foos;
    }
    output;
    handleClick() {
        const startTime = performance.now();
        this.foos.map(foo => foo);
        const endTime = performance.now();

        console.log(this.output = `Map call took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`);
    }
}
```

In general, if you're passing arrays/objects around, and you do the appropriate copy, you'll get 100,000x performance or so.

This is a known problem, and is likely to be partially mitigated by the new [Lightning Web Security](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_security_intro.htm&type=5&release=234), but you can definitely do yourself a favor with copy algorithms to produce a local copy. You'll use potentially a lot more memory, but you'll get insane performance boosts. You'll want to use this unless/until you discover that this is no longer an issue.

Note that this should be applied at every level of the hierarchy (e.g. every @api should copy incoming values) to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing the Lightning Web Security. By turning on the beta setting in my scratch org I can see the performance improvement! My actual scenario is a bit more complex and I used a JSON string and I'm parsing it to the bottom level components as you mentioned in your other post. It has a small performance hit obviously but is ok for my use case right now.