# Does lwc combobox have a maximum number of options?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to diagnose a performance problem, and we have isolated it down to a rendering cycle around a [`lightning-combobox`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-combobox/example). The architecture is roughly as follows:

- TopLevel - component that organizes multiple different types of child component
- SourceLevel - child component dispatches an event up which contains the relevant data
- TargetLevel - child component which has the combobox

  - Has an `@api` enabled attribute with an `options` property
  - This `options` property is bound to the combobox with a getter

    ```javascript
    get options() { return this.someAttribute && this.someAttribute.options; }
    ```

As the size of `options` grows, performance exponentially degrades. Based on some profiling, if we represent with `x` the number of options, the execution time in milliseconds is roughly `1.86 x^2 - 77.95 x + 923`. With 125 items, it was averaging over 20 seconds to execute. The picklist that brought this problem to light has 136, and execution time was about triple the above for most of the day.

We tried swapping out the `combobox` for a custom component loosely based on [`lwc-combobox-autocomplete`](https://github.com/benedwards44/lwc-combobox-autocomplete) by [Ben Edwards](https://github.com/benedwards44). This custom component uses `<ul>` and `<li>` tags with no `lightning-combobox` anywhere, and suffered similar performance problems.

We're not sure where else to look at this point to investigate/remediate this performance issue. But I would like to know if others have experienced similar performance problems binding picklists to large collections of options (100+). Or if there is some issue with the binding structure, it is not immediately obvious to me how to fix it. I can add any information still missing if needed.

Comment: How do you get the options? Could it be an apex issue retrieving the options instead of a frontend issue?

Comment: No, we have isolated the problem to when we _assign_ the value in the success callback. As soon as that line fires, it bricks the UI for the long delay.

Comment: Just to clarify; this is related to browser rendering thread performance, right? You don't have any plugins listening for DOM mutations do you?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/333161/2984). Possible solutions: try enabling Lightning Web Security or use a setter and copy the data at each level before passing it on or using the data (use the copied version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove it's not LWC itself, I wrote the following code:

```xml
<template>
    <lightning-combobox label="Select Option" options={options} placeholder="Select an Option"
        onselectoption={handleOptionChange} class="slds-m-bottom_small"></lightning-combobox>
    <c-combobox-autocomplete label="Select Option" options={options} placeholder="Select an Option"
        onselectoption={handleOptionChange} classes="slds-m-bottom_small">
    </c-combobox-autocomplete>
    Performance:<span class="output"></span>
</template>
```

---

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

const options = [...Array(1000).keys()].map((key)=>({ label: `Option ${key}`, value: key }))

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  options = options;

  selectedOptionValue;
  selectedOptionLabel;

  constructor() {
    super();
    performance.mark('start');
  }
  renderedCallback() {
    performance.mark('end');
    this.template.querySelector('.output').innerText = ` ${performance.measure('start', 'end').duration}ms`;
  }
  handleOptionChange(event) {
      this.selectedOptionValue = event.detail.value;
      this.selectedOptionLabel = event.detail.label;
  }
}
```

---

Your milage may vary, but I'm getting an output of a rendering time of 0.2 milliseconds between constructor and renderedCallback. For 1,000 items. For both lightning-combobox and combobox-autocomplete, running at the same time.

I suspect that you're running into [this problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/333161/2984). Locker Service is known to have abysmal issues with performance. Try [Enabling Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_enable) or using the solution provided in the first link of this paragraph, namely, copying the elements at each level:

```javascript
get options() { return [...(this.someAttribute?.options || [])]; 
}
```

Edit: I [added a child component](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/wmbcKdhFgpjRjN7UI1fW/src/app.css?p=stories) to use an @api attribute, and it changed the render time from 0.2ms to 0.3ms. The boundary layer hardly adds any extra rendering at all, which should be further proof.

[Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/kx37pBFb7gCN4OnyuGuu/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: My read of the documentation indicates you can only `Enable Lightning Web Security in an Org` if it contains no Aura. Is that a correct interpretation of the first sentence? I did fix the issue by cloning the right attribute, though it was still tricky to figure out where.

Comment: @AdrianLarson You *can* enable it, but it's not recommended at this time. See [When to Enable Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_when) for specifics, but the idea is that there are some issues when communicating across the Aura/LWC boundary with LS/LWS. At minimum, you'd need to test to make sure LWS doesn't break anything. I've turned LWS on in a few orgs, nothing broke, despite having Aura. Just make sure you test thoroughly.

Comment: Yeah that won't fly up the chain. 